# coordinating geoFire Ready and key_entered events

Tags: angularjs, geofire

I am new to GeoFire, FireBase and Angular. I am trying to create a function that will take some coordinates and return some objects in vicinity of those coordinates.

I return a promise from the function which I assign to a scope variable used in the view hoping that when the promise is resolved by the ready event the array of objects in vicinity will be available.

```
obj.findGroupsInViscinity = function(pos){
    var gFire = factoryAuth.geoFire;
    var fbaseRef = factoryAuth.usersRef;
    var groupsInQuery = {};
    var groupsInQueryAr = [];
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var geoQuery = gFire.query({
      center: [pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude],
      radius: 2
    })

    geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(groupId, groupLocation, distance) {
      console.log("--> key_entered 1");
      groupsInQuery[groupId] = true;

      // Look up the vehicle's data in the Transit Open Data Set
      fbaseRef.child("groups").child(groupId).once("value", function(dataSnapshot) {

        console.log("--> key_entered 2");

        // Get the vehicle data from the Open Data Set
        group = dataSnapshot.val();

        // If the vehicle has not already exited this query in the time it took to look up its data in the Open Data
        // Set, add it to the map
        if (group !== null && groupsInQuery[groupId] === true) {
          console.log("Adding group", group);

          // Add the group to the list of groups in the query
          groupsInQuery[groupId] = group;
          groupsInQueryAr.push({"name": group.name});
        }
      })
    }) // end ke_entered monitoring

    geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
      console.log("GeoQuery ready event received. groupsInQueryAr = ", groupsInQueryAr);

      deferred.resolve(groupsInQueryAr);
      geoQuery.cancel();
      console.log("GeoQuery canceled");
    }) // Cacnel the geoQuery once we have gotten all the groups in viscinity

return deferred.promise; // Return a promise that will be resolved when ready event fires
}
```

Included below the console output from calling this function.
[image]

What I notice is that the key_entered part of the code is called twice in succession but before the code to process the key_entered event completes, the ready event is called because all key_entered events have fired. So while the key_entered part of the logic is building out the array I want to pass in resolving the promise, it is not ready at the time I resolve the promise in the ready event.

How can I ensure that I resolve the promise after all key_entered events have been processed and my array of objects has been built out properly?

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that this is a bit of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I would suggest you just load the restaurants into your view as you get them. This will probably be a better user experience in most cases.

That being said, if you want to do what you are asking about, you can make it work by using [$.all()](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all). Essentially, create and return your deferred promise. Start with an empty list and for every `key_entered` event, push a new promise onto the list. Then, in your `ready` event callback, do a `$q.all()` on the list of promises and once they complete (in the `then()` of the promise), do the `deferred.resolve()`.